# Is $R[X]$ Dedekind finite if $R$ is?

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a (possibly non-commutative) ring with unity, with the property that whenever two elements $a,b \in R$ satisfy $ab = 1$, we also have $ba = 1$.$^{[1]}$ Now let $f,g \in R[X]$ such that $fg = 1$ in $R[X]$. Prove that $gf$ = 1 as well.

What I initially tried to do was to use induction on the sum of degrees of the polynomials. The base case, where both of them are constant polynomials, is easily done. To move to higher cases, the problem that I am facing is that I am having to substitute values of $X$ to boil down to lower cases which I don't think is a right way to do. I also tried to assume
$f(X) = a_0 + a_1X + ... + a_nX^n$
$g(X) = b_0 + b_1X + ... + b_mX^m$
and then try induction assuming
$(f - a_nX^n)(g - b_mX^m) = (g - b_mX^m)(f - a_nX^n) = 1$
but I am getting nothing useful from here.

Ok upon retrying just now I think I have a rough sketch: we can try comparing coefficients
So suppose $fg = 1$
Hence $a_0b_0 = 1$ and so $b_0a_0= 1$ as well
Now $a_1b_0 + a_0b_1 = 0$
$\implies b_0(a_1b_0 + a_0b_1)a_0 =0$
$\implies b_0a_1 + b_1a_0 = 0$ as we already have $a_0b_0 = b_0a_0 =1$
And this pre-multiplying by $b_0$ and post-multiplying by $a_0$ and then simplifying using previously found equations seems to work, but it is tedious to really write down all this. A slick way of concluding would be appreciated. Maybe we can now apply induction and make it simpler.

$^{[1]}$ Such a ring is called "Dedekind finite" or sometimes "directly finite."

Answer (score 3):

Rings are assumed to have a unity. Recall the easy to prove fact that given a ring $R$, an element of $R[[X]]$ is invertible if and only if its constant term is invertible in $R$.

Now let $R$ be a Dedekind-finite ring, $f, g \in R[X]$, a subring of $R[[X]]$, with $fg = 1$. Dedekind-finite means that if an element has a left (or right) inverse, it is invertible.

Writing $f = \sum_k a_k X^k$ and $g = \sum_k b_k X^k$, it follows that $a_0b_0 = 1$. Since $R$ is Dedekind-finite, $a_0$ is invertible in $R$, so $f$ is invertible in $R[[X]]$ with inverse $g' \in R[[X]]$.

Thus in $R[[X]]$, $fg'=g'f=1$. The unity of $R[X]$ is the unity of $R[[X]]$, so $fg =fg'$, and hence $g'fg= g'fg'$, so $g=g'$. Thus $gf=1$, so $R[X]$ is Dedekind-finite.